# Trying to use Jquery/javascript to calculate form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having a terrible time trying to calculate the value of two form fields.  I'm constantly getting "NAN" which would indicate non-numeric input, this is despite the fact that the form fields are only populated with numbers.

In response I tried to use ParseInt to get a numeric value.  This also fails to yield a successful result.

This is what I have so far.  Any help is appreciated.

```
$('#value-calc input').change(function () {

    var valueINT = parseInt($('#value'),10);
    var quantINT = parseInt($('#quantity'), 10);
    var math = ((valueINT/quantINT)*1000);

    $('#cpm').val(math);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/greyoxide/YRWAA/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `.val()` method after your selectors to get the value they hold

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YRWAA/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing in strings when you refer to elements by ID with that jQuery.

Perhaps try `$('#value').val()` in the `parseInt` methods instead.

Comment: Thanks I didnt understand that I needed to qualify the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#value-calc input').keyup(function () {

var valueINT = $('#value').val();
var quantINT = $('#quantity').val();
var math = ((valueINT/quantINT)*1000);
$('#cpm').val(math);

});
```